# Solving recurrence relation, no clue how to approach

Tags: recurrence-relations

I'm trying to solve the following recurrence relation

> $$T(n)\le T\left(\frac{3n}{4}\right)+T\left(\frac{n}{\log n}\right)+C\cdot{n}\log\log n$$

The answer should be $T(n)=\Theta(n \log\log n)$ and I can show it by induction, but how should one guess that this is the form of answer?

Comment: I would first look to the master theorem; to simplify the two $T$'s on the RHS, I would focus on the one that has the largest growth (for $n$ sufficiently large, $\frac{3n}{4}>\frac{n}{\log n}$).  So then, for $n$ sufficiently large, $T(n)\leq 2T(\frac{3n}{4})+C\cdot n\log\log n$.  I haven't done out the details to see if this actually works, however.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, Following your suggestion, we have $f(n)=n\log\log n=O(n^2)$ and $2<\log_{\frac{4}{3}}2$, thus we have case 1 of master theorem, i.e $T(n)=\Theta \left(n^{\log_{\frac{4}{3}}2}\right)$ which is not strict...

Comment: You could, instead, choose $n$ even larger so that one of the other cases of the master theorem apply.  For example, $T(\frac{n}{\log n})<\frac{1}{3} T(\frac{3n}{4})$

Comment: @MichaelBurr, this one is great, thanks!

Comment: To get Case 3 to apply, don't you need then something strictly less that $1/3$? (to get "$a< 4/3$")? @MichaelBurr

Comment: @Clement C., this is true, we need little less than 1/3 in order to apply it. The inequality is indeed strict.

Comment: I agree that the constant needs to be a little smaller; thanks for noticing @ClementC.